# Do zip files store their creation time in the zip itself?

Tags: zip

I've heard that this is the case, but how can I access this information? Neither 7-Zip nor WinRAR will tell me. Also, is it true that the seconds are stored by even seconds (2-second resolution)?

Comment: What is the OS we talk about?

Comment: @RomeoNinov : Doesn't matter.  Windows XP Service Pack 1a, if you like.  This is determined by the ZIP file format specification, and so this is not at all impacted by which operating system the computer is using.

Comment: @TOOGAM, this is VERY important as in UNIX/Linux you do not have creation time as meta for file/directory!

Comment: @RomeoNinov : The question is "Do zip files store their creation time in the zip itself?"  This has nothing to do with what information is stored in the filesystem structure.  Whether UNIX/Linux typically stores creation information in the filesystem's meta data has absolutely nothing to do with what this question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.  [PKWare's AppNote.txt](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT) says that the file stores modification time, but does not creation time.  So if you modify a Zip file with compliant software, you'll get an updated modification time, thereby losing track of the creation time.

Therefore, there is no way to access the creation time, because that isn't stored.  As for the modification time, looking at the 11th and 12th bytes will contain the bits (as noted by [Florian Buchholz's "The structure of a PKZip file"](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/buchhofp/forensics/formats/pkzip.html).  You would then need to interpret manually.  That may be the fastest approach: I've checked another couple of software packages and the results didn't seem to readily show the modification time.  (It would not be challenging to create a program to show this.  You might even get several solutions if you submitted this to [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).)  (Using the operating system's file time information may be a more convenient method of getting the modification time.  In contrast to my (first) comment to Romeo Ninov, seen under the question, the process would be a bit more specific to which operating system is used.)

As for the 2-second precision, the answer is yes.*  The AppNote.txt shows the modification time is stored in 2 bytes, and section 4.4.6 says "The date and time are encoded in standard MS-DOS format."  [Some FAT16 documentation](http://simba-os.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library-reference/filesystems/fat16.html) confirms the possible values for keeping track of seconds are 0-29, and that value is doubled (so the result is that you only get even-numbered seconds).

- Having said that, I just used the 7-Zip command line tool (7z.exe l filename.zip) and it showed me a time including 13 for the number of seconds.  That was the time for a specific compressed file, not the ZIP file itself.

Comment: There are extensions for zip to store the Unix timestamp. I assume 7-zip may be using that, or there is another extension for NTFS attributes.